# Bitmap to Iplimage conversion produce wrong color

Tags: c++, .net, opencv

i am trying to convert a bitmap to opencv image i am using pinvoke by sending the Bitmap.Scan0 and in the unmanaged side i am creating iplimage by using the byte array  the solution is seems to work but not always ! only if i created the image on my pc using my grahpic device but it fails on another the image colors seems to be not right and the image is shifted  i am suspecting that i should transfer the bitmap to DIB how can this done ?

```
IplImage* image= cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),depth,3)
memcpy(image->imageData,(uchar*)(bitmap),width*height*3);
```

Comment: i don't know how to use GetDIBits what HDC should i provide ?

Comment: What's in `bitmap`? How is it generated? Bitmap's origin is at bottom-left while IplImage's at top-left.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

`IplImage` stores pixels in the **BGR** order while `HBITMAP` expects them to be RGB.

Luckely, for you, the whole `IplImage` can be converted from BGR to RGB with:

```
cvCvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2RGB);
```